# iOS : Inifinite Loop setting rightView's frame of UITextField with IBInspectable attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, interface-builder, ibinspectable

I inherits my "MFTextField" class from UITextField.
I want to customize the frame of the "rightView" property of the UITextField with an IBInspectable property from Interface Builder. To do that :

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface MFTextField : UITextField <UITextFieldDelegate, MFComponentValidationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGRect errorViewFrame;

@end
```

And in my MFtextField.m :

```
-(CGRect)rightViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    if(CGRectEqualToRect(CGRectZero, self.errorViewFrame)) {
        //default position
        CGRect rightViewRect = self.errorView.bounds;
        rightViewRect.size.height = bounds.size.height - 4;
        rightViewRect.origin.y = 2;
        rightViewRect.origin.x = bounds.size.width - rightViewRect.size.width - 2;
        return rightViewRect;
    }
    else {
        //Custom position
        return self.errorViewFrame;
    }
}
```

I Declare my rightView :

```
self.errorView = [[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] loadNibNamed:@"MFErrorView" owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
self.rightView = self.errorView;
self.rightView = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Okay. Now i see the my rightView with de default position on IB, and i'm allowed to customize its frame :

[image: In InterfaceBuilder before to customize rightView frame]

But when i want to change the value of my "Error view frame" IBinspectable property, XCode begins an infinite loop then crashes... It seems that the method **rightViewRectForBounds:** is infinitely called by iOS now...

Any idea ?

Comment: You have put no reference at where or why the method `rightViewRectForBounds` is used, from your code alone I can tell that it is never called neither by you or by IB.

Comment: I do, but i forget to put it in my question. edited.

Comment: The question still doesn't show how `rightViewRectForBounds` is *supposed* to be called.

Comment: Oh yes it does. rightViewRectForBounds is a method of UITextField that is automatically called when a rightView is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found where was the problem. In my opinion it's an iOS bug : 
the constraints i defined in my XIB file specify that a "Info Detail Button" must stick the XIB rootView (defining top, left, bottom and right margin between my button and the xib root view).

When i change the first value of my IBInspectable property (i set 1 instead of 0 for X value, for example), the size of my view is to small compared to the constraints defined in the XIB loaded in the rightView : it crashes.

However, when i change the XIB size (for example 2x2 instead of 35x35), it causes no problem to render it.

I decided to change my constraints with : fixed height and fixed width for my Add Button (35x35) and center it horizontally and vertically.

No crash anymore.